# Powershell Script Cannot Find Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.HttpResponseException

Tags: powershell

I have a Powershell 7.3.3 script that uses a custom Powershell module that contains

```
  try {
      ...
    }
    catch [Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.HttpResponseException] {
      ....
 }
```

The script runs fine from VSCode, but throws an error when I try to run it from Powershell Terminal.  "Unable to find type [Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.HttpResponseException]".

Adding Add-Type -AssemblyName Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.HTTPResponseException to the script file does not make a difference.

If I remove the HttpResponseException from the catch statement it runs fine, but I lose some error handling options.

Any idea how to fix this?  I want to run the script daily via Task Scheduler, but cannot until this error is figured out.

Comment: Instead of `Add-Type`, call `Import-Module Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility`

Comment: You may accidentally be running _Windows PowerShell_ instead of PowerShell (Core) 7.3.3 in your regular terminal (console). `[Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.HttpResponseException]` isn't available in Windows PowerShell.

Comment: in your task scheduler make sure you're using `pwsh.exe` and not `powershell.exe`

Comment: Thanks for the quick response guys.  I was running the script from Windows Powershell. Opening a command line and running it with pwsh.exe worked, but only AFTER I also added Add-Type -AssemblyName Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.HTTPResponseException to the top of the script file.  My script is now running fine from Task Schedule!!  All three replies made a difference.  Thanks again.